# How to get "heading" text left and right aligned over a table in HTML

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a page which renders correctly in IE and Chrome, but not in Firefox. The result I want in all three browsers looks like this:

[image: Desired rendering]

...but in Firefox, it looks like this:

[image]

The code I have so far is this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>My title</title>
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        margin-left:50px;
        margin-right:50px;
      }
      .title{
        float:left;
        font-size:x-large;
      }
      .right-aligned{ 
        float:right;
        font-size:smaller;
        text-align:right;
      }
      table,tr,td,th {
        border:1px solid black;
      }
      tr.clsTable {
        background-color:lightgray;
      }
      td.tableContainer {
        padding:0px;
      }
      table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
      }
      td.spacer {
        border-right:hidden;
      }
      table.clsSubTable {
        border-top:0px hidden;
        border-right:0px hidden;
      }
      td,th {
        padding:3px;
      }
      th {
        background-color:burlywood
      }
      .no-result{
        position:absolute;
        top:50px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="title">My title</div>
    <div class="right-aligned">Right<br/>aligned</div>
    <br/>
    <div>
      <table class="clsTable" width="100%">
        <tr>
          <th>Some heading</th>
          <th>Some other heading</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="clsTable">
          <td>Some data</td>
          <td>Some other data</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong, and what do I need to do to fix the Firefox problem, without "breaking" the current behaviour in IE and Chrome ("right-aligned" text maintains its relationship with the right edge of the table as the browser window is resized)?

Answer (score 1):

This is a side-effect of misusing floats. The best solution is to use `display:inline-block` instead.

([jsBin](http://jsbin.com/tudujapuvu/edit?html,output))

```css
.wrp {
    font-size: 0; /* Prevent white-space between tags being rendered as text */
}
.title, .right-aligned {
    display: inline-block;
}
.title {
    width: 75%;
    font-size:x-large;
}
.right-aligned { 
    width: 25%;
    font-size: 10pt;
    text-align:right;
}                                                                                         body { font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin-left:50px; margin-right:50px; } table,tr,td,th { border:1px solid black; } tr.clsTable { background-color:lightgray; } td.tableContainer { padding:0px; } table { border-collapse: collapse; } td.spacer { border-right:hidden; } table.clsSubTable { border-top:0px hidden; border-right:0px hidden; } td,th { padding:3px; } th { background-color:burlywood }
```

```html
<div class="wrp">
  <div class="title">My title</div>
  <div class="right-aligned">Right<br/>aligned</div>
</div>                                                                                      <div><table class="clsTable" width="100%"><tr><th>Some heading</th><th>Some other heading</th></tr><tr class="clsTable"><td>Some data</td><td>Some other data</td></tr></table></div>
```

Comment: Thanks... most of the way there... it is making an even split between .title and ,right-aligned; how do I give ,right-aligned a smaller part, either as a percent of the available width or as a fixed width (with .title getting the rest)?

Comment: I've updated my example to show you. Basically as long as the two percentages add up to 100% then you're good. If you want a fixed width on the right column, that would require a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

some browsers don't support some CSS3 stuff. -moz- usually does the trick. 
lets say firefox doesn't support a margin-right in CSS. You can say -moz-margin-right: 40px;

Comment: and you forgot a ">" for "</style>"